# $F(u,v,x,y)=0$ and $G(u,v,x,y)=0$ can be solved iif Jacobian determinant is not zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

On Schaum's outlines Advanced Calculus, I saw that

> A necessary and sufficient condition that the equations $F(u,v,x,y)=0$ and $G(u,v,x,y)=0$ can be solved for $u$ and $v$ is that $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$ is not identically zero in a region in $\mathbb{R}$

But I considered the following example: Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ be $f(u,v)=\left(x(u,v),y(u,v)\right)=(u^2,v)$. Then the Jacobian determinant of $f$ is

$$
        \det(J)=\begin{vmatrix}
        2u & 0\\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=2u
$$

Since $\det(J)=0$ when $u=0$, we cannot solve for $u,v$ at that point. But is this a contradiction? Because I always have

$$u=\pm\sqrt{x}$$

$$v=y$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that being able to solve for $u$ and $v$ means that given a value $(x,y)$ we can determine a unique $(u,v)$ such that $f(u,v) = (x,y)$. With the function $f(u,v) = (u^2,v)$ we can't find an open set around $(0,v)$, for any $v \in \mathbb{R}$ where we can solve for $u$ uniquely. No matter how small a region $R$ we take around this point then restricting the domain of $f$ to $R$, there will always be an $\epsilon >0 $ such that $(-\epsilon,v) \in R$ and $(\epsilon, v) \in R$ so the pre-image of $\epsilon^2$ will not have a unique element.

As an aside, if you are interested, the theorem quoted is a case of the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).